# Python The repetition result is always double

Tags: python, for-loop

I still new to python. I have a problem when I try to use looping. I have two variables and the second variable always gives me the same result. In my example, I have a database like this:

```
id | name
1    porce
2    cadilcac
3    honda
4    toyota
```

First, i tried to loop over `id`, it's working well. But when I tried to loop over `name`, the result is always wrong, like this:

```
1.porce
2.porce
3.porce
4.porce
```

The result what I want is:

```
1.porce
2.cadilcac
3.honda
4.toyota
```

And this is my code :

```
number = 0
for id_id in id_number:
    dd = name # here i call the name by id
    number += 1
    print(number)
    print(dd)
```

Comment: show you whole code. You are probably forgetting to access the right variable

Comment: You mean Porsche? Also, what is `name`?

Comment: Sorry, but your code is not helpful. There are two variables without any source and it's unclean what your comment means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# using list
    vehicles = ["Honda", "Porche", "Cadilcac", "Toyota"] 
    number = 0
    for vehicle in vehicles:
        number += 1
        print(number),  # ',' is used to print both columns in a single line
        print(vehicle)

    # using dictionary

    vehicles = {1: 'porce',2:'cardilac',3:'honda',4:'toyota'}
    number=0
    for id_id in dict:
            dd= dict[id_id] 
            number += 1
            print(number),
            print(dd)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you did't use vehicle list directly for looping brother, for example:

```
vehicles = ["Honda", "Porche", "Cadilcac", "Toyota"]
number = 0
for vehicle in vehicles:
    number += 1
    print(number)
    print(vehicle)
```

I hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

```
#set counter
count = 1

#set list
my_list = ['porce', 'cadilac', 'honda', 'toyota']

#loop through the values and use the counter to assign to the first part of
# your print statement
for item in my_list:

    # this format would be the same as the one that you requested
    print('{}.{}'.format(count,item))
    # increment the counter
    count += 1

However, if you directly import from a database, a set of tuples would be a better structure than that of a list. Otherwise, it would be better to employ a dictionary type structure.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
vehicles = ["Honda", "Porche", "Cadilac", "Toyota"]
number = 0
for vehicle in vehicles:
    number += 1
    print(str(number) + ". " + vehicle)
```

I hope this is what you mean.